# Getting multiple date ranges between SQL query and adding up the data accordingly

Tags: sql, go

I need to select a certain range of dates after I have already completed the query `SELECT * FROM <DB>`.

For example:

```
var (date string
     views int
     impressions int)

for query.Next() { 
    err := query.Scan(&date, &views, &impressions)
    // handle the err
    // get the range of dates for each month
    // add up all the views and impressions in that specific range
}
```

The 'date' var will obviously be all of the dates in the database query.

Dates are formatted as: `2017-10-01` (October 1st as an example) and there are about 300 in October and 100 in November.

From here, I need to add up all the values (views and impressions), but only per date range.

So I would get something like:

`2017-10-01` to `2017-10-31` has `54` impressions
`2017-10-01` to `2017-10-07` has `5` impressions as an example.

Any idea how I'd come about this issue?

Comment: Each scan is only going to pull one row.  Assuming the format of the row is a date to view/impression association, with the date being non-unique, use a map of string (or a time format, if you want to convert the date string) to the view/impression data for that date, and add the data to the relevant map entry on each query scan.  For ranges, just do a custom addition over the map.  Might be easier if you use a date format that can be made easily sequential (like Julian dates) rather than strings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not exactly sure how I'd do that if the dates are sometimes duplicates and multiple columns. The views/impressions were an example, but here is what I have so far: https://gist.github.com/Noy/9596c8cae488631406018b53849a3294

Comment: Well, your double loop is certainly less efficient than a map strategy.  Your double loop version will require a number of iterations approaching NumRows * NumUniqueDates.  A map-style strategy requires only NumRows iterations.  O(n) vs. O(n^2) scaling.  If you did it instead by, say, a slice using the day of the year as the index (which is similar to a map style, mechanically), compiling the summed stats between any particular dates becomes trivially easy to calculate.

Comment: Example: https://play.golang.org/p/HVCPkcMJzv

Comment: Oh awesome. Thank you for that example. That makes a lot of sense actually. Appreciate the help.

Comment: gg man, thanks so much for the help. Learned a lot from this.

Comment: Going to go ahead and post it as an answer, so this question actually has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the best bet in these cases is to use a map-style strategy to keep track.  For example, a map[date]data would allow you to keep a unique entry for each date.  Dates, however, have a beneficial optimization, in that they can easily be represented by integers (the day of the year), and the number of options is small enough to not be a memory issue.  This means we can use a slice instead of a map and get the benefits of ordering (Go maps are randomly ordered in a for loop) while still using it *like* a map.  For example:

```
type Data struct {
    // fields
}

const dateFormat = "2006-01-02" // only parse the date

dayStats := make([]Data, 366) // account for leap years

for query.Next() {
    var datestr string // can make this a time.Time, if your date format scans properly
    var dr Data
    if err := query.Scan(datestr, /* other fields */ ); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    date, err := time.Parse(datestr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    dayStats[date.YearDay()].someField += dr.someField
    dayStats[date.YearDay()].someOtherField += dr.someOtherField
    // other fields...
}
```

Now let's say we want to calculate the stats between a 01 October and 31 October:

```
start := time.Date(2017, time.October, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
end := time.Date(2017, time.October, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

var total Data
for day := start.YearDay(); day <= end.YearDay(); day++ {
    total.someField += dayStats[day].someField
    total.someOtherField += dayStats[day].someOtherField
    // other fields...
}
```